# Why in R is the result of division by 0 (zero) Inf (infinity) instead of undefined?

Tags: r

In [R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) the following code produces a result of Inf [(infinity)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Literal-constants).

```
7/0
[1] Inf
```

In mathematics the [result of division by 0 is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Comment: From the Wiki article you link to: *"Depending on the programming environment and the type of number (e.g. floating point, integer) being divided by zero, it may generate **positive or negative infinity** by the IEEE 754 floating point standard [...]"* (bold-face mine). And from [Double precision vectors](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html): *"All R platforms are required to work with values conforming to the IEC 60559 (also known as IEEE 754) standard."*

Comment: I think you need to read the entire Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

R conforms to [IEE754](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html)

Even an integer like 7 is a double in R

```
> typeof(7)
[1] "double"
```

Under IEE754, the result of division by 0 is [Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling)

```
Division by zero: an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0). By default, returns ±infinity.
```

Comment: Hi Matt. Not sure if this question warrants an answer, in particular seeing that you answered your own question within less than 10 minutes (10 minutes that you could've/should've spend reading the full articles you link to yourself). Furthermore, this is very clearly explained in the R documentation. I would recommend deleting post the question and answer.

Comment: Hi Maurits, thanks for your comments. I was also wondering about this. As I researched my question, I come upon the answer. I then wondered if I should post the question and answer to share with others, then I read this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ which seems to suggests it is encouraged. I can imagine that some other user may ponder the same question I did.

Comment: `7L` is an *integer* in R, `7` is not, so one misunderstanding is in R's base classes.

Comment: @MattG I agree with the general sentiment from the SO blog post you link to. However, your question is very clearly, unambiguously and explicitly addressed in the official R documentation. I don't think SO is the right place to re-iterate information from sources that should've been consulted prior to posting here. Furthermore, the fact that the information is readily available is demonstrated by you taking less than 10 minutes to obtain the answer to your own question. And lastly, I had *already* answered your question in my first comment before you posted your answer.

Comment: r2evans, 7L/0 also equals "Inf", I guess this implies integers in R use IEEE754 too. Is that the case? My confusion comes from my experience in languages like Java where an integer/0 is an exception and a floating point type/0 is Infinity.